# Slow query when sorting and filtering

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongodb version 3.6.5. I would like to do a query on a collection, and then sorting it based on date. I work on a (what I think) is a pretty large dataset, currently 195064301 data in this collection, and it's growing.

Doing the filter or the sort in separated query work perfectly

```
db.getCollection('logs').find({session: ObjectId("5af3baa173faa851f8b0090c")})
db.getCollection('logs').find({}).sort({date: 1})
```

The result is returned is less than 1 sec, but if I try to do it in a single query like so

```
db.getCollection('logs').find({session: ObjectId("5af3baa173faa851f8b0090c")}).sort({date: 1})
```

Now it take about 5minutes to return the data. I was thinking it was a index problem, but as far as I can tell, the index seems fine

```
> db.logs.getIndexes();
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "client1.logs"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "session" : 1
        },
        "name" : "session_1",
        "ns" : "client1.logs",
        "background" : true
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "date" : 1
        },
        "name" : "date_1",
        "ns" : "client1.logs",
        "background" : true
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "user" : 1
        },
        "name" : "user_1",
        "ns" : "client1.logs",
        "background" : true
    }
]
```

I'm still new to mongo, I try thoses request directly in the console, I also tried to use the reIndex() method, but nothing really help.

So I'm hoping there is a solution on this.

Thanks.